# send parameters in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have this code on Flutter and I found a big problem: I need to send a parameter (`isAdmin`) to other widget in other `page`. I know that I have to send this by parameter in the widget, but the issue is the parameter `isAdmin` needs to access to the database to achieve his real value.

On summary, the widget loads before the access to the database had ended, so the real value of `isAdmin` is not sent. How can I do that?

```dart
class Inicio_User extends StatefulWidget {
  Inicio_User({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Inicio_User> createState() => _InicioUserState();
}

class _InicioUserState extends State<Inicio_User> {
  int _paginaActual = 0;
  bool isAdmin = false;
  List<Widget> _paginas = [
    widget_productos(isAdmin),
    widget_restaurantes(),
    widget_perfil()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final User? usuario = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String? email = "";
    String? uid = "";
    String? nombre = "";
    final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    if (usuario != null) {
      email = usuario.email!;
      uid = usuario.uid;
      firestoreInstance
          .collection("Usuario")
          .where("email", isEqualTo: email)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        value.docs.forEach((result) {
          // HAGO UPDATE DEL UID EN CASO DE QUE SEA NULL (PORQUE SE ACABA DE REGISTRAR)
          if (result.get('UID') == 'null') {
            print("\nMODIFICANDO UID PORQUE ERA NULL\n");
            firestoreInstance
                .collection("Usuario")
                .doc(result.id)
                .update({"UID": uid}).then((_) {
              print("success!");
            });
          }
          isAdmin = result.get("isAdmin");
          _paginas[0] = widget_productos(isAdmin);
        });
      });
    }
    return Scaffold(
            body: _paginas[_paginaActual],
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  _salir(context);
                },
                label: Text('BIENVENIDO A CELIPAL - TU AMIGO CELIACO',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255))),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.logout,
                  color: Colors.white70,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              /*
        CurrentIndex es para que por defecto se muestre el BottomNavigationBarItem numero 0 del array (el primero, en mi caso seria la listaproductos.)*/
              currentIndex: _paginaActual,
              onTap: (index) => {
                setState(() => {_paginaActual = index})
              },
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Productos"),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.deck_outlined), label: "Restaurantes"),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.account_box_rounded), label: "Mi perfil")
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  void _salir(BuildContext context) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you can use `initState` to load data using future method. After loading/getting data, populate the variables like `email`..... Also make sure to remove these variable outside/before build method.

Comment: Hi! I'm new using flutter so I don't know how to do that :( Could you be more specific? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
void whois() async{
  final User? usuario = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (usuario != null) {
    email = usuario.email!;
    uid = usuario.uid;
    await firestoreInstance
        .collection("Usuario")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: email)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((result) {
        // HAGO UPDATE DEL UID EN CASO DE QUE SEA NULL (PORQUE SE ACABA DE REGISTRAR)
        if (result.get('UID') == 'null') {
          print("\nMODIFICANDO UID PORQUE ERA NULL\n");
          firestoreInstance
              .collection("Usuario")
              .doc(result.id)
              .update({"UID": uid}).then((_) {
            print("success!");
          });
        }
        setState(() {
          isAdmin = result.get("isAdmin");
          _paginas[0] = widget_productos(isAdmin);
        });

      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! It works but it is always repeating the function again and again, it's like it entered in an infinite loop

Comment: I call whois() inside initState instead of build and IT WORKS!!! THANK YOU!! Gracias de verdad!!! I've been trying to solve this for a long time :((( Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm so glad because it's my first time to help someone in StackOverflow and it worked!! you're welcome and good luck.